# Extract Text from CSV file

Tags: text, csv

I have a CSV file that has only 1 column, but has close to 1500 records.

I'd like to extract information from each record, e.g.,

"The sample battery has a Voltage: 11.1V, and capacity: 4500mAh"

I'd like to extract out 11.1 and place in another file, i.e., after "voltage: ", before "V". If the record does not have "voltage: ", I would like to have a empty line in it.

I'm in a Linux environment, what's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: It seems your file contains two columns (there's a comma in there)

Comment: Do I get this right? Every line in that CSV looks like the one you described? So first of all we need to check if 'Voltage:' and 'V' exist, then look for the number in between and export it to another file?

Comment: Assaf, that depends if you are following the CSV convention that quoted statements are strings than can contain commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python

```
import csv
source = open( "myfile.csv", "rb" )
rdr= csv.reader( source )
for row in rdr:
    print "The sample battery has a Voltage: %.1fV, and capacity: %dmAh" % ( float(row[0]), int(row[1]), )
```

Will get you started with pulling data from a CSV file.

---

Apparently (based on comments) the file looks like this.

```
"The sample battery has a Voltage: 11.1V, and capacity: 4500mAh"
```

Which could be a 1-column CSV.  Or a single row with bonus quotes.  Let's pretend it's a 1-column CSV.

```
import csv
import re
v_pat= re.compile(r' (\d+\.\d+)V' )
mah_pat = re.compile(r' (\d+)mAh' )
source = open( "myfile.csv", "rb" )
rdr= csv.reader( source )
for row in rdr:
   v_match= v_pat.search( row[0] )
   mah_match= mah_pat.search( row[0] )
   if v_match and mah_match:
       print v_match.group(1), mah_match.group(1)
   else:
       print # empty line -- not very informative
```

Something like that might be appropriate.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly opposite of what I intend to do. Basically it's a CSV file from a shopping cart (exported with phpMyAdmin), and I want to extract out the numbers instead.

So it's like whenever the program sees "Voltage:", it would extract the real number (floating point in this case) just after it.

Comment: Please clarify your question, to include this new information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by a single column CSV file; if it has a single column, isn't it just a text file?

Anyway, if each line looks like above and we have a file like this:

```
bash-3.2$ cat example.txt
The sample battery has a Voltage: 11.1V, and capacity: 4500mAh
The sample battery has some other info but no v entry
The sample battery has a Voltage: 12.1V, and capacity: 4200mAh
```

Then you can achieve this easily strip out the 11.1 with a regexp and retain the indexing with like this:

```
bash-3.2$ sed -e 's/.*Voltage: \([^V]*\)V.*/\1/' -e 's/^The.*//' < example.txt
11.1

12.1
```

Which can be adjusted if I've misunderstood the format of the not voltage containing lines.  Note that my expressions are very fragile with respect to your formatting, and can be improved.  Also note that I didn't include quotations, as your intent was unclear. The above needs to be (trivially) adjusted to work with them.